# How to plot barchart with error bar and dots using lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to plot bar chart with errorbar and dots representing single data value using `lattice`, what I expected is the figure like [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/sthda-upload/figures/r-graphics-essentials/006-plot-grouped-data-r-graphics-cookbook-and-examples-for-great-data-visualization-mean-median-plots-for-grouped-data-with-error-bars-2.png) from [this page](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/132-plot-grouped-data-box-plot-bar-plot-and-more/#:%7E:text=ggbarplot(ToothGrowth%2C%20x%20%3D%20%22dose%22%2C%20y%20%3D%20%22len%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20add%20%3D%20c(%22mean_se%22%2C%20%22jitter%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%20%3D%20%22supp%22%2C%20palette%20%3D%20c(%22%2300AFBB%22%2C%20%22%23E7B800%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20position%20%3D%20position_dodge(0.8))). However, `lattice` outputs wrongs after I tried to use `panel.barchart` combind with `panel.xyplot`:

```
barchart(len ~ dose + supp,
  data = ToothGrowth,
  panel = function(x, y, ...) {
    panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
    panel.xyplot(..., jitter.x = TRUE)
    panel.segments(x0 = x, y0 = y-0.5, x1 = x, y1 = y+0.5)
}
```

I would like to know can `lattice` do this job, and if can, how to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: see https://www.nrel.colostate.edu/this-is-how-i-did-it-added-error-bars-to-a-lattice-bar-chart-in-r/

Comment: Thank you for the help! Besides the error bar, I would like to have dot points too. It is hard for me to figure out how to plot points with bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling this a barchart is misleading, it's more like a strip plot with a confidence interval. Here's one possible implementation:

```r
panel.ci <- function(x, y, col.symbol, ...)
{
    col <- col.symbol
    ## points
    panel.points(jitter(x, amount = 0.2), y,
                 col = col, pch = 16, cex = 1.5, alpha = 0.5)
    ## summaries
    m <- tapply(y, x, mean)
    s <- tapply(y, x, sd) / sqrt(tapply(y, x, length))
    ## 'bars'
    ux <- sort(unique(x))
    w <- 0.45 # rectangle half-width
    panel.rect(ux - w, 0, ux + w, m, border = col, lwd = 2)
    ## confidence interval
    panel.arrows(ux, m - 1.96 * s, ux, m + 1.96 * s, col = col,
                 length = 0.1, angle = 90, code = 3, lwd = 2)
}
xyplot(len ~ supp | factor(dose), data = ToothGrowth, groups = supp,
       layout = c(3, 1), ylim = c(-1, NA), pch = 16, col = 2:3,
       panel = panel.superpose, panel.groups = panel.ci)
```